# SwiftUI ScrollView renders sub views too early before they enter screen

Tags: swiftui

I recently started studying ios/swiftui by developing a small application, which has a list of cards to display picture and message loaded from server.

I was using *List* to hold those cards but the default list 'decoration' (divider, arrow, tapping effect) looks not very good together with my card view. I disable them by adding below code into *SceneDelegate*:

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
```

And having some sort of hack to hide the arrow:

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<self.store.data.count, id: \.self) { idx in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: self.store.data[idx])) {
            EmptyView()
        }.frame(width: 0).opacity(0)
        ItemCard(item: self.store.data[idx])
    }
    BottomLoader().onAppear {
        if self.store.status != .loading {
            self.store.load() 
        }
    }
}
```

But, the problem is that hiding List's selection style and separator color in SceneDelegate applies to all the lists in App, and I do have couple lists (such as the one in settings) need those style.

Then I tried to change the card holder from *List* to *ScrollView* but it leads to another trouble, the *onAppear* callback of last view (BottomLoader) gets called at the same time with ScrollView *onAppear* gets called.

As far as I understand, *onAppear* is supposed to be called when view is rendered and shown. List as the item holder, does not have to calculate the full height of all items, that is probably why List renders only the items about to enter screen. But *ScrollView* does need to know the full height of all items and that is why all the items get rendered.

Below are two small segments to show different behaviors of List and ScrollView:

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<100) { idx in
        Text("item # \(idx)").padding().onAppear { print("\(idx) on appear") }
    }
}
// only 18 logs printed
```

And:

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(0..<100) { idx in
        Text("item # \(idx)").padding().onAppear { print("\(idx) on appear") }
    }
}
// all 100 logs printed
```

Is there any way, to let ScrollView acts like List, to render its subviews when they about to enter screen.
Or, is there any way, to disable those default styles to a specific List, not globally?

Comment: `Appearance` is applied from the place it is changed and for all subviews, so answer on "disable those default styles to a specific List" is simple - apply your style only in view they are going to be, say in `init`. The other question is worse - there is no official way to do that.

Comment: @Asperi, thanks! so it is still globally applying to all the Lists that instantiated after I set the appearance in one view, meaning that I will need to be very careful about the sequence of creating each views. Or, to set appearance right before using every List. Hmmm... it works, just, not feeling so well about it ..

Comment: Read overview section carefully - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

Comment: @Asperi, this is exactly what I expected, to get those different types of list 100% under control by holding them with different containers. But it seems that this is not so hard to apply in UIKit, but using it in SwiftUI is not very straightforward, it looks like I will have to make a custom container class conforming protocol UIAppearanceContainer? Or maybe this is just a newb question?

Comment: Well, actually formally, IMO, using `appearance()` in SwiftUI is a hack at all, because depends on reverse engineered knowledge that inside some SwfitUI components *use*, now!, UIKit components... tomorrow they might, and rather do, stop using them and all shipped applications which used those hacks will stop working, with unpredictable result.

Comment: @Asperi, LOL. Now it looks like I should start studying ios development with UIKit, instead of SwiftUI, which is still kinda too young for a real world production.

Comment: You say it )) ... or use SwiftUI-only inside SwiftUI, and UIKit-only inside UIKit, and combine those two worlds as officially documented via corresponding representables.

Comment: @Asperi, right! I almost forget that we can use them in same project, you save my day, thanks a lot!